# Laravel api search function with multiple params

Tags: php, laravel, rest

I almost read all article in google and posts in stackoverflow, but I couldn't find the right solution or I don't get it. anyway, I want to make a search function in Laravel API, so I started with:

```
public function search(Request $request) {
    $data = $request->get('data');

    $search = Post::where('title', 'like', "%{$data}%")
             ->orWhere('user_id', 'like', "%{$data}%")
             ->get();

    return response()->json([
        'data' => $search
    ]);
}
```

This working fine, and by below URL return me data:

`http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/search?data=22`

```
{
    "data": [
        {
            "id": 10,
            "title": "some",
            "created_at": "2019-11-02 07:56:40",
            "updated_at": "2019-11-02 07:56:40",
            "user_id": "22"
        }
    ]
}
```

But I want to get data for each parameter like this, and also remove params from url, instead send as form data:

`http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/search`

form data:

```
{
user_id: 22
}
```

So what I tried so far is:

```
   public function search(Request $request) {
        $user_id = request('user_id'); // this return 22
        $title = request('title');

        $search = Post::where('title', 'like', "%{$title}%")
                 ->orWhere('user_id', 'like', "%{$user_id}%")
                 ->get();

        return response()->json([
            'data' => $search
        ]);
    }
```

But it return all data, not just data with user_id-> 22, Any idea?

**Result:**

```
{
    "data": [
        {
            "id": 8,
            "title": "some",
            "created_at": "2019-11-02 07:55:57",
            "updated_at": "2019-11-02 07:55:57",
            "user_id": "12"
        },
        {
            "id": 10,
            "title": "some",
            "created_at": "2019-11-02 07:56:40",
            "updated_at": "2019-11-02 07:56:40",
            "user_id": "22"
        },
        {
            "id": 11,
            "title": "some",
            "created_at": "2019-11-02 07:56:45",
            "updated_at": "2019-11-02 07:56:45",
            "user_id": "4"
        },
        {
            "id": 12,
            "title": "some",
            "created_at": "2019-11-02 07:56:47",
            "updated_at": "2019-11-02 07:56:47",
            "user_id": "42"
        }
    ]
}
```

I want it just return id 10 because it only data with user_id 22.

Comment: Change `->orWhere` to `where` to make the condition as `AND`.

Comment: @JordanLipana oh really.. my bad. thanks it solved my issue.

Comment: Just change `->get()` to `->pluck('user_id')` like this and you will get the `user_id` only

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Fixed the issue by changing `->orWhere` to `->where` to make the condition as AND.

Answer (score 1):

I use `post` request when multiple parameters are being used.

Then in function I filter data like shown below:

```
public function searchFilters($request){
    $query = User::query();
    if($request->has('name')){
        $query = $query->where('title','like','%'.$request->name.'%');
    }
    if($request->has('salary_negotiable')){
        $query = $query->where('negotiable',$request->salary_negotiable);
    }
    if($request->has('city_ids')){
        $query = $query->whereIn('city_id',$request->city_ids);
    }
    if($request->has('experience_level_ids')){
        $query = $query->whereIn('experience_level_id',$request->experience_level_ids);
    }
    if($request->has('job_type_ids')){
        $query = $query->whereIn('job_type_id',$request->job_type_ids);
    }
    if($request->has('language_name')){
        $query = $query->whereHas('jobLanguageIds',function ($q) use($request){
            $q->select('languages.id','languages.name')->where('languages.name',$request->language_name);
        });
    }
    return $query;
}
```

This function is just returning a `$query` instance so that I can re-use and append more queries where ever I want. Be careful though with appending `orWhere[...]` constraints as they may overrule all the other conditions if you don't wrap them in an overall `where()`.

You can also change `return $query` to `return $query->get();` if you want the actual result from the database straight away.